# Showing a list of files in a ListView

Tags: android, file, directory, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm wondering how to show files from a directory in a ListView`. The files can be listed with:

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
```

and added to the `ListView` via `ArrayAdapter` but I don't get the usage of the `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: what is exactly your question? there is plenty of SO questions about 'how to manage an arrayAdapter', 'how to create a listView'. For you I think you want to just display the name of different files from a folder, to a listview. You will have to pass an ArrayList of Strings to your adapter. Look at the official documentation there is some examples about how to do a ListView.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you want to show the names of the files from that directory so you could try this:

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
   theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
}
```

The adapter to use with the list :

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item, theNamesOfFiles);
```

For anything more complicated than showing the names of the files  you have to implement a custom adapter.

Comment: How about names of the file plus the date of creation/modified?

Comment: @SiKni8 The `File` class unfortunately exposes only the date of the last file modification and not the creation date. To show that besides the file's name you could use a custom adapter or a `Hashmap` containing the data and use a `SimpleAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think Modified Date should suffice for me. One question I have is I want to display a custom icon followed by the filename top right of icon and modified date bottom right of icon. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Thanks Its working fine. I need onItemClicklistener actions also please help me.

Comment: @vijay If you need to do some actions on clicking an item in the list then simply set a OnItemClickListener on the ListView and do the action.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use something like this for a sorted `String` of `filenames`:

```
File dataDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
File fileDir = new File(dataDirectory, "data/com.yourapp.app/files");

String[] listItems = fileDir.list();
Arrays.sort(listItems);
```